# display:none Bootstrap modal property not changing when popping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myMod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a Checkbox to pop that modal :

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="publicado" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#myMod">
```

but when I check the checkbox the background is set to black and the modal is not popping, searching at the console I saw the property `display:none` from the modal class not changing. So if I disable that the modal pops, and start working subsequently, can anybody shed a light? What is going wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that a modal can be toggled from a checkbox width `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes ? Did you tried to use jQuery events instead ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just used what it is in the docs, obviously isnt from a checkbox,, as you can see i have Vue also, so I just dont want to use jquery, but now as you suggest that posibilty I would have to check, @Michel.

Comment: changing the modal bound to a button doesn't work also

Comment: check if `important` rule set to `display:none` and I don't know what is this `v-model="publicado"` but the code in question is working http://jsfiddle.net/x4mxmmen/

Comment: hello@Shehary v-model="publicado" is the http://vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-model Im using to populate the checkbox from the DB so I can edit every row. As the fiddle works I will have to update my question as I have a table which is fetched dinamycally. I might be using wrong the bootstrap modal call to the rows. Thanks for helping

Comment: Well yes, I should make another question with a deep explanation involving all I have. Laravel and partials.

Comment: this is the new question regarding vue and modals.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149197/how-to-pass-data-to-a-vuestrap-modal-component