# How to Pass Data to a vuestrap Modal component

Tags: laravel-5.1, vue.js

Im trying to pass some table data to its child vuestrap Modal component. The modal will be reused by all the Td's where the checkbox is calling the modal.

```
<div id="ordertbl" class="table-responsive">
<table  class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
 ...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr v-repeat="slides">
<td>@{ {NAME}}</td>
<td>@{ {MESSAGE}}</td>
<td> <input type="checkbox"  v-on="click:showMod = true" v-model="published" > </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<modal title="Modal" show="@{{@showMod}}" effect="fade" width="400">
 <div class="modal-body">You will publish NAME, MESSAGE</div>
 </modal>
 </div>
```

when the checkbox is clicked. As you can see every row in the table has one checkbox so the data to be passed to the Modal will be unique to its row.
As Im new to Vue, besides Im trying to use Vuestrap to not reinvent things, 
I dont know how to give that Data to the Modal when it pops.

```
   new Vue({

        el:'#ordertbl',

        components: {
            'modal':VueStrap.modal
        },

        data: {
            showMod: false,
            sortKey: '',
            reverse:false,
            slides: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                message: '',
                published: ''
            }
 },
```

Basically I want to do the following

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

Pass the related data to the Modal, but with Vuestrap

Comment: here is a screen of what I have http://workupload.com/file/92Q7vehU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `v-for="slide in slides"`. So every `tr` can get one of the slide object. Then you can pass it as a props to modal.

Extra ajax request is not required.

Comment: thank you for answering. Indeed Ajax isnt Necessary, . Vue does all the job.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it with an ajax request depending on the Id clicked.